# Break if statement c++ error

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, break

I'm writing linear and quadratic probing hash table program.

This is a for-loop I used for linear probing function and it works perfectly fine.

```
//when there's a collision increase i by 1 until finding empty slot
       for(i = (hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize; i <tableSize; i++)
           if(a[i] == -1){
               a[i] = hashVal;
               break;
           }
```

so I wrote a for loop again in quadratic probing function to deal with collision

```
//when there's a collision increase i by i^2
    j = 0;

    for(i=((hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize); i < tableSize; i++)
        j = i^2;
        if(a[j] == -1){
            a[j] = hashVal;
            break;
        }
```

But when I compile quadratic probing, I'm getting this error

```
error: 'break' statement not in loop or switch statement
```

I am really confused why it causes error in the second one while it is fine in linear probing. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: You're missing curly braces after the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(i=((hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize); i < tableSize; i++)
    j = i^2;
```

this is your cycle, since you didn't put curly braces around it.

fix is simple, put those braces:

```
for(i=((hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize); i < tableSize; i++)
{
    j = i^2;
    if(a[j] == -1){
        a[j] = hashVal;
        break;
    }
}
```

Rule of thumb - always put curly braces when you use cycle or if-statement, because it helps you to not make such errors as this.

Answer (score 1):

Because only the immediately following statement is the for loop body, so

```
for(i=((hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize); i < tableSize; i++)
    j = i^2; // the body of for loop

// not for loop body from here (note the correct indent position)
if(a[j] == -1){
    a[j] = hashVal;
    break;
}
```

For your 1st code sample, the whole `if` statement is the for loop body, so it works fine.

To fix your code, you could use braces to make it a [compound statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Compound_statements), which may consist of multiple statements.

```
for(i=((hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize); i < tableSize; i++) {
    j = i^2; 

    if(a[j] == -1){
        a[j] = hashVal;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put braces around the body of your `for` statement. This works in the first example because the body is just the `if` statement, but in your second example, only `j = i^2;` is parsed as part of the `for`. The code is equivalent to:

```
//when there's a collision increase i by i^2
j = 0;

for(i=((hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize); i < tableSize; i++) {
    j = i^2;
}

if(a[j] == -1){
    a[j] = hashVal;
    break;
}
```

You can fix this by adding braces in the correct place:

```
//when there's a collision increase i by i^2
j = 0;

for(i=((hashVal % tableSize+1) % tableSize); i < tableSize; i++) {
    j = i^2;
    if(a[j] == -1){
        a[j] = hashVal;
        break;
    }
}
```

A good rule of thumb is to put braces around any loop body which is more than a single line long. Many would recommend even putting braces around single lines in case you want to add more to the loop body at a later time.